# Cannot connect after upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: internet

I upgraded to 13.10 and now I have no internet connection. When I do `ifconfig`, it shows my inet addr: 127.0.0.1. When I do `sudo lshw -C network`, it shows `*-network DISABLED`, even though the `Enable Networking` is checked.

How do I repair this?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have installed the correct driver for your wireless adapters.
You could get in to the Additional Drivers menu from the settings menu.